# Google dictionary api does not return pure json?

Tags: json, google-api

I have the following code:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(string.Format(@"http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q={0}&sl=en&tl=en", "bar"));
```

This returns something like this:

> dict_api.callbacks.id100({"query":"bar","sourceLanguage":"en","targetLanguage":"en","primaries":[{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"bar",....

Why is it returning a function rather than just the json?  Am I using web client incorrectly?

Comment: What does your question really have to do with C#?

Comment: Just the example that is in c# I suppose.

Comment: But it's clearly "just some code making a web request" - it's not like the response is going to be different if it were fetched with curl, or Java, etc.

Comment: Alright, please update the tags to what you think is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, this is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - JSON which is "padded" with a function call to allow cross-domain data transfer. I strongly *suspect* that if you pass in a different callback name on the URL, you'll see that other name come back in the response.

(Note that although I work for Google, this answer is not an "official" response from Google in any way, shape or form.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use check this out :

[json_decode for Google Dictionary API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889764/json-decode-for-google-dictionary-api)

They actually modify the resultant jsonp to get a json